# Check if the number of element is equal to a specific number PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, row

From the image below, you can see there is a empty space in second row (red rectangular), by right it should filling up the empty space. This is happening because the first image title is longer than others.

I know by using HTML code, I can use `clear: both;` and put under the first row to solve it. But my info is read from database. Following is my php and mysql code, I have simplified it, please ignore the method I use to display the image.

[image]

```
$selectSQL="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(published_date,'%d %M %Y') AS eventDate FROM media";

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectSQL)){
   <div style="float:left">
     <img src="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>" width="150px" height="212px">
     <div><?php echo $rows["title"]; ?></div>]
     <div><?php echo $rows["eventDate"]; ?></div>
   </div>
}
```

I have one solution, which is compare the number of element = 5. Something like the following code. But I'm not sure how to check it the number of element. Please advice or please suggest me if you have another solutions. Thanks!

```
if($num_element==5){
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
```

Comment: Why not simple css 3 selector `nth-child(5)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I try to prevent use CSS3 because some of my clients are still using old IE version :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ i = 0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectSQL)){
   <div style="float:left">
     <img src="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>" width="150px" height="212px">
     <div><?php echo $rows["title"]; ?></div>]
     <div><?php echo $rows["eventDate"]; ?></div>
   </div>
$i++;
if($i % 5 == 0){
 echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
}
}
```

you can try this code to check the number of items totally displayed and after 5 elements it will print a clear div

Comment: Cool! You reminded me, I should use this method earlier, LOL. Thanks! By the way, %5 is the answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()` to concat your title when it is very long. you can try it like this:

```
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectSQL)){
        <div style="float:left">
          <img src="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>" width="150px" height="212px">
          <div title="<?php echo $rows["title"];?>">
              <?php if(strlen($rows["title"]) > 6){
                         echo substr($rows["title"],0, 6).'...';
                    }else{
                         echo $rows["title"];
                    } ?>
           </div>
          <div><?php echo $rows["eventDate"]; ?></div>
        </div>
    }
```

With this code you can customize the length of the words in your title.

Comment: yes, good suggestion! I will use this to prevent the super long title.

Comment: Is it I answer your question with this answer? please bottoms up if it is help you of your question

Comment: Your answer is not the answer I want, Exprator gave me the correct answer. But this code is suitable to use to prevent a very long title. Will up vote for you.